# Function which combine new columns from a table to another table

Tags: list, haskell

I need a little help with two tables issues:
How to achieve simple horizontal union of 2 tables?
Like this:

```
table2table :: Table -> Table -> Table

table1 = [["Zoe", "2", "1"], 
         ["Mark", "2", "5"]]

table2 = [["Zbir", "4", "7"], 
         ["Nels", "1", "3"]]

table2table = [["Zoe", "2", "1"], ["Zbir", "4", "7"], 
              ["Mark", "2", "5"], ["Nels", "1", "3"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a general way to perform such combination, you can make use of `concat . transpose`:

```
> concat . transpose $ [table1, table2]
[["Zoe","2","1"],["Zbir","4","7"],["Mark","2","5"],["Nels","1","3"]]
```

And it works for more than two lists, if you need it:

```
> concat . transpose $ [table1, table2, table1]
[["Zoe","2","1"],["Zbir","4","7"],["Zoe","2","1"],
 ["Mark","2","5"],["Nels","1","3"],["Mark","2","5"]]   -- manually formatted
```

`transpose` groups them "by columns", `concat` flattens the lists back.

Another way to mix the lists is by doing it in the [`diagonal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.1.2/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:diagonal) manner:

```
> diagonal [table1, table2]
[["Zoe","2","1"],["Zbir","4","7"],["Mark","2","5"],["Nels","1","3"]]
```

For two lists the results are the same as `concat . transpose`, but with more lists they are different.

```
> diagonal [table1, table2, table1]
[["Zoe","2","1"],["Zbir","4","7"],["Mark","2","5"],
 ["Zoe","2","1"],["Nels","1","3"],["Mark","2","5"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you want to *mix* two lists together - a simple solution could be

```hs
mix :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mix xs [] = xs
mix [] ys = ys
mix (x:xs) (y:ys) = x:y:mix xs ys

table2table :: Table -> Table -> Table
table2table = mix
```

**note** that this does not really take the "table"-like representation into account but you really just have a list-of lists and Haskell does not really care how you write down the parts of this list into lines in the editor.

Comment: There's cute trick to reduce the number of cases: swap the arguments at each recursive call. `mix [] ys = ys; mix (x:xs) ys = x : mix ys xs`